# No Drainage Around Concrete Basement Floor

Tags: basement, drainage, sump-pump

This question/comment is in regards to the sump pump question I had yesterday.
While digging the hole to set my new sump pump basin I realized that there was very little if any gravel under the actual concrete. Again, the house was built in 1964 and it appears that they poured the concrete floor directly over the undisturbed or compacted soil (good old Missouri clay!), without using a gravel base. So my guess is, there is absolutely no drainage around the foundation and no place for the water to go except into the house between the walls and the floor.  And if that's the case, in order to eliminate the water problem, I will need to break out the floor along the wall where the water is coming in, dig a trench over to the sump pump, then back-fill the trench with gravel before finishing the concrete.  Correct?? 
So my question now is, (unless someone has a simpler solution!), is how deep and wide would I need to make the trench to ensure proper drainage?  The basin I put in is 18"x22" deep.

Thanks again!!